# How to show progress bar in actionbar, in place of other actionbar item

Tags: android, android-actionbar, progress-bar

What I want to implement is I have a refresh button in actionbar, when I press this refresh button to refresh feed, I want a progress bar (circle) in place of refresh button.

I am able to implement this 
[image]

using:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
```

but what I need is the *refresh button* replaced by progress circle.

Answer (score 0):

In past i have implemented the following:

1. refresh button in action bar.
2. when user press the refresh button the view is animated
3. stops programatically

You can use the following code:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu) {
    refresh = menu.add(0, R.string.menu_refresh, Menu.FIRST, getResources().getString(R.string.menu_refresh));
    refresh.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);
    final ImageView iv = new ImageView(this);
    iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_refresh, this));
    iv.setClickable(true);
    iv.setOnClickListener(this);
    refresh.setActionView(iv);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(final View v) {
    startAnimation();
    loadData();
}

private void startAnimation() {
    if (refresh == null) {
        return;
    }
    refresh.getActionView().setEnabled(false);
    final Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.clockwise_rotation);
    animation.setRepeatCount(50);
    refresh.getActionView().startAnimation(animation);
}

private void stopAnimation() {
    if (refresh == null) {
        return;
    }
    final View v = refresh.getActionView();
    if (v.getAnimation() != null) {
        v.getAnimation().cancel();
        v.setEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]

[image]

[image]